# Bootstrap row aligning issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

The following is my HTML:

```
<div class=container">
   <div class="row">
    <h2 class="text-center">Enter your name below</h2>
    <div class="col-md-6 center">
        <img class="profile-picture" ng-src="../Content/images/default-avatar.png" src="../Content/images/default-avatar.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 center">
        <h3>Profile name: N/A</h3>
        <h3>Status: Waiting for user input</h3>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My css is the following (along with bootstrap):

```
.profile-picture
{
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
}

.center
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
}
```

This produces the following output:
[image]

**The way I want it to display is as shown below:**
[image]

How can I achieve this? Shouldn't they get displayed on the SAME line seeing as they are part of the same row? Each has a length of 6 so why don't they horizontally align?

Comment: Did you get it to work? I left a few comments and suggestions in my answer.

Comment: FYI - the edit you made to your post, the `<h2>` heading shouldn't be left alone in the row like that. Wrap it in a `<div class="col-md-12" />` or look at my example below (the answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem is you're removing the necessary float on the columns** (by setting `float:none` to .center). Remove that `.center` class altogether, it's not needed. You are also missing row divs...

Note, I added a `row` around the the `h2` tag as well. For ease-of-use and proper formatting, that tag needs to be wrapped as well. Helps keep the formatting in check. ;)

Also, you shouldn't have two `<h3>` tags one after another like that. Use `<p>` instead of the second h3 - or better yet, just use one `<h3>` tag and use `<br />` to break the one h3 into two lines (see below).

```
<div class=container">
    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="text-center">Enter your name below</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="profile-picture" ng-src="../Content/images/default-avatar.png" src="../Content/images/default-avatar.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Profile name: N/A <br />
                Status: Waiting for user input</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see. However I would like the elements to be centered on the row (sort of like text-center) - how could I achieve this?

Comment: Create a ".text-center" class...assign it the `text-align: center` CSS. Apply it to the element. As someone else mentioned, it's not wise to apply styling to bootstrap elements - like the columns or rows. But as long as it's simply classes and nothing to do with floats, width, padding or margins, you should be okay. In this case, I'd be comfortable applying a "text-center" class to the columns.

Comment: If this works for you, please don't forget to accept the answer. ;) Check off the checkmark to the right of my answer. It's how we get paid around here...lol

Answer (score 1):

**Never** apply any styles or classes to elements with grid classes, if you're not really know what you are doing. Use a nested div instead if you need to change something:

```
<div class=container">

  <h2 class="text-center">Enter your name below</h2>

  <div class ="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class ="center">
         <img class="profile-picture" ng-src="../Content/images/default-avatar.png" src="../Content/images/default-avatar.png">
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class ="center">
        <h3>Profile name: N/A</h3>
        <h3>Status: Waiting for user input</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With Bootstrap,  you have to include a `div` with an class of `row`, so something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 center">
        <img class="profile-picture" ng-src="../Content/images/default-avatar.png" src="../Content/images/default-avatar.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 center">
        <h3>Profile name: N/A</h3>
        <h3>Status: Waiting for user input</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

See [Bootstrap's documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) on their grid system.